# How to distribute/deploy a Visual Studio Add-in

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, windows-installer, visual-studio-addins, vsix

I created my own Add-in with Visual Studio 2010. This Add-in is loaded at the startup of Visual Studio and it adds an entry in the Tools menu. The action of the Add-in is executing by clicking on its entry in the Tools menu.
The Add-in works well, but now I want to create an installer or something to deploy it on others computers.
I tried to create an MSI project, but I don't know where to copy the dll of the Add-in and how to register it in Visual Studio.
Then I tried to create a VSIX project, I managed to install the extension but my entry in the Tools menu is not visible/displayed.
Anyone knows a good way to deploy the Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VSIX installers are used for deploying **Visual Studio 2010 extensions**. I'm not sure it works for add-ins. I would go with MSI. Here you will find a tutorial:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/AddinCustomAction.aspx

Comment: Thanks, it's what I need. I hoped that there would be a native solution in VS :(   I found the MSDN doc updated for VS 2010 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19dax6cz.aspx